# power series for matrix with elements smaller than 1

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, power-series

If I have a square matrix A such that all elements $|a_{ij}| < 1$ does this guarantee that all my eigenvalues will also be less than 1 and that the power series $S = I - A + A^2 - A^3...$ will converge?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix

$$
\begin{bmatrix}0.5 & 0.5 \\ 0.5 & 0.5 \end{bmatrix}
$$

has eigenvalues $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda = 1$.

Going even further, consider the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0.5 & \sqrt{0.5} \\ \sqrt{0.5} & 0.5 \end{bmatrix}.
$$

This has eigenvalues $\lambda = 0.5 \pm \sqrt{0.5}$, one of which is strictly larger than $1$.

If you want some elements to be negative, (slight modifications of) these examples still work:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0.5 & -0.5 \\ -0.5 & 0.5 \end{bmatrix}
$$

has eigenvalues $0$ and $1$, e.g.

(note that in general, you can change the sign on both the off-diagonal elements of my examples, and the characteristic polynomial is unchanged, so the eigenvalues are the same)

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add one condition - each row has the same number of positive and negative elements so the 1st row could be [.5 -.5] but both value cannot be positive.  I was similarly trying to come up with counter examples and forgot to specify this condition.

Comment: ok, these same basic examples work in that case (see my edit above). you should also edit that condition into your original question (so it's easier for people to read in the future)

Comment: yea, you're right....I really want my matrix to be invertible. It represents a stable system so I feel like it should be but I just don't have enough information to prove it.  ::sigh::

Comment: note that if you modify my second example (so the $\sqrt{0.5}$'s become $-\sqrt{0.5}$) then the eigenvalues are the same (so one e.val is $> 1$) but the matrix is invertible.

Comment: good point.  In reality, I'm trying to invert something of the form (I+A) where A is the matrix we've been discussing above.  I know that A is not diagonalizable (then I could have used Sylvester's thm) because all the row sums = 0 so I was trying to show that the power series converges since S*(I+A) = I but that doesn't seem easy either

Comment: "All row sums $=0$" definitely does **not** imply "not diagonalizable". In fact, "having distinct eigenvalues" $\Rightarrow$ "diagonalizability", so all of the above examples are diagonalizable, including the "$0.5, -0.5$ " one.

Comment: "All row sums $=0$" **will** imply the matrix is non-invertible though: in this case the vector $\xi = (1,1,\dots,1)^T$ will be an eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: yea, the matrix A is not invertible but I+A may be invertible.  I thought for a matrix to be diagonalizable such that $A=PDP^{-1}$ required invertibility and symmetry.  You're saying it will work if I have distinct eigenvalues?

Comment: Yes, distinct eigenvalues are sufficient (but not even necessary!) for diagonalizability. You're thinking of **orthogonal** diagonalizability: "$A$ is orthogonally diagonalizable (i.e. the matrix $P$ is orthogonal; equivalently all eigenvectors are orthogonal) **if and only if** $A$ is symmetric". Note that invertibility never entered into it either; $A$ non-invertible will mean some of the diagonal elements of $D$ (i.e. the eigenvalues of $A$) are zero, but otherwise has no effect.

Comment: just looked it up and you're right again, seems like unique eigenvalues is the key here...don't know why I thought different.  Ok, well now I need to think if I can show my matrix can have unique eigenvalues.  thanks!

Comment: Yep, there are actually relatively few matrices that are non-diagonalizable (see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Matrices_that_are_not_diagonalizable) And you're very welcome. Good luck. – BaronVT 6 mins ago